# Button not working in UIView for UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've created a header for the first section in my UITableView. The Header is created by a view in .nib file. I've connected the button to the Views owner which is a class called HeaderSection which is a subclass of UITableViewHeaderFooterView.

Here's the code for what should happen when the button is clicked.

```
#import "HeaderSection.h"

@implementation HeaderSection

- (IBAction)touchButton1:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Touch button 1 tapped!");
}

@end
```

And here's a screen shot of things overall.

[image]

The problem is when I tap on the button, it doesn't detect the tap, instead the cell below the button detects the tap and the code runs accordingly (brings on a new UIViewController).

How can I make it detect the top button?

Here's more code from my main ViewController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

    UINib *sectionHeaderNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"headerNib" bundle:nil];

    NSString *SectionHeaderViewIdentifier = @"sectionHeaderIndentifier";

    [self.tableView registerNib:sectionHeaderNib forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];


  self.iconSets = [IconSet iconSets];

  self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;

  UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGestureRecognized:)];
  [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

  self.filteredIcons = [NSMutableArray array];

}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 60.0f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString *SectionHeaderViewIdentifier = @"sectionHeaderIndentifier";

    HeaderSection *sectionHeaderView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];


    return sectionHeaderView;
}
```

And here's a screen shot of the view in the .xib (I've made the underlying view dark grey to stand out).

[image]

Comment: Is your header cell `userInteractionEnabled`?

Comment: I'm not using a cell, I'm using a separate view in a .nib.

Comment: Okay, is that separate view in a .nib `userInteractionEnabled`?

Comment: Where would that be?

Comment: Ah I found it, yes it is, and also for the button.

Comment: If you enable `clipsToBounds` on your header, does it still display the same or does it get cut off?

Comment: It looks like you still haven't solved your height problem from the last question (the first cell is partly underneath your header). What height is the header view in the xib?

Comment: @rdelmar, I've added a screen shot of the .xib.

Comment: @IanMacDonald how do I enable clickToBounds?

Comment: There's a check box in the Attributes Inspector for clipsToBounds. You should check it for both of the views you have in your xib.

Comment: You mean clip subviews? I did that and the dark grey view and the buttons dissapeared.

Comment: Ok, that means you didn't set some of the constraints properly. When a button is outside the bounds of its superview, it won't receive touches.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69237/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-phil).

Answer (score 0):

One problem you have is that in the .xib file, the top-level object must be set, in the idendity inspector, to be the custom UIView subclass that it is, or nothing will work.

However, it looks like other things are going on. The gray from the tableview cell underneath shouldn't be peaking out on the right of the footer. Is this being added in the tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: method of the UITableViewDataSource? It can adjust the headerView's frame there to be the width of the tableView. Depending on what the button is going to do, it might also need a reference to the view controller.

If the search bar and buttons are going to stay on top always, they don't really need to be a header. On that .xib you have, just put a tableview underneath the button bar. Create a ViewController with that file as the .xib, then connect that tableView's dataSource and delegate to that View Controller. You may need to create a ViewController with built-in xib to do this automatically, in or out of storyboards.

Freestanding xibs are discouraged but I think they're perfect for this case, tableView/collectionView reusable views. But if its on top of the table, not in it, it should be part of the view controller that contains the table.

Comment: I wanted to keep using a UITableViewController rather than going with just a UITableView because I thought you get little extras with the TableController which you don't get by just using a TableView? I've added some more of the code in my question.

Comment: Looks solid, but you still need to set the custom class of the .xib. Open the xib, and select the top-level "View" in the object inspector list on the left. With this selected, in the identity inspector to the right (third icon, looks like a newspaper) set the custom class to HeaderSection. It should autocomplete. The name in the left will then change to HeaderSection.